# Is standing apart 2m an appropriate Social Distancing measure for choirs

Tags: infection, covid-19, epidemiology, airborne-transmission

In our choir, we are discussing measures to slow the spread of the novel Coronavirus in our community. However, I lack understanding about how the virus spreads in a closed room. The German Public Health authority recommends "Social distancing" of 1-2m.

However, in a choir, many people are singing all the time on the same location. Singing also produce respiratory droplets [[src1]](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK143281/) and I don't know how long those droplets stay infective.

- [src1] states that droplets dry out within 2m. Are Coronaviruses only infective while suspended in these droplets?
- Given the long exposition of the people to each other and the long duration of singing, are the recommendations of Social Distancing applicable to choirs?

Comment: We now know that talking, and worse singing, exhales virus into the air.

Comment: @GrahamChiu thanks for the info, could you provide a source to your claim?

Comment: https://www.livescience.com/covid19-coronavirus-transmission-through-speech.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand any choir being compatible with any definition of social distancing.  If the German Govt is asking you to practice social distancing it means meeting another person at a distance.  You can not continue your choir.

> What is social distancing?
>
> Social distancing measures are steps you can take to reduce the social interaction between people. This will help reduce the transmission of coronavirus (COVID-19).
>
> They are:
>
> Avoid contact with someone who is displaying symptoms of coronavirus (COVID-19). These symptoms include high temperature and/or new and continuous cough
>
> Avoid non-essential use of public transport, varying your travel times to avoid rush hour, when possible
>
> Work from home, where possible. Your employer should support you to do this. Please refer to employer guidance for more information
>
> Avoid large gatherings, and gatherings in smaller public spaces such as pubs, cinemas, restaurants, theatres, bars, clubs
>
> Avoid gatherings with friends and family. Keep in touch using remote technology such as phone, internet, and social media
>
> Use telephone or online services to contact your GP or other essential services

https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/covid-19-guidance-on-social-distancing-and-for-vulnerable-people/guidance-on-social-distancing-for-everyone-in-the-uk-and-protecting-older-people-and-vulnerable-adults